# Java DateFormat not converting correctly

Tags: java, date-formatting

I am probably overlooking something, but parsing from string to date is not working correctly for me.
I have String: "20110705_060229" which is format: "YYYYddMM_HHmmss"

this piece of code:

```
Date triggermoment;

public void setTriggermoment(String triggermoment) throws ParseException {
  DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYYddMM_HHmmss");
  this.triggermoment = formatter.parse(triggermoment);
}
```

gives me as output (when I run toString() method on triggermoment):
Mon Jan 03 06:02:29 CET 2011

Why is it not parsing the day's and month's correctly? It should be June 7 instead of Jan 3.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use `y` for years. `Y` is used for week year :

```
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyddMM_HHmmss");
```

Output:

```
Sat May 07 06:02:29 CEST 2011
```

> It should be June 7 instead of Jan 3

The 5th month in the year is may, not june.

Comment: Thank you very much! Indeed it is may. I think I need some sleep ;-) Problem solved now!

Answer (score 2):

MM is month whereas mm is munutes. y is for year and Y is used for Week year.

Try yyyyddMM_HHmmss instead of YYYYddMM_HHmmss